# Update Components When Data in dataService Changes

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I am trying to update all components to reflect changes made to the dataService, currently when I add an item to the list it displays in the footer (footer area in solid green)

[image: displayed in footer]

however if I click the remove button, it is removed from the footer (footer area solid green) but is not updating the body component (button should change back to nominate from nominated when item removed from list)

[image]

How do I fix this, so that when the remove button is clicked, the nomination button will update also? Thank you!

I have 3 components stacked like below:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<app-body></app-body>
```

Inside my footer.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent {

  nominations = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.nominations.subscribe(noms => this.nominations.push(noms));
    this.nominations.splice(0, 1);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    
  }

  remove(indx: number){
    //remove movie from array in footer
    this.nominations.splice(indx, 1);
    //remove movie from dataService
    delete this.dataService.nominations[indx];
  }

}
```

inside my body.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.css']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {

  movies: string[];
  inptMovie = "";
  nominations = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.nominations.subscribe(noms => this.nominations.push(noms));
    this.nominations.splice(0, 1);
   }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    
  }

  //check to see if the movie is already nominated.
  checkNominations(mov: Object){
    let arr = [];   
    arr.push(mov);
    var isInArray = this.nominations.find(e => e.imdbID === arr[0].imdbID) !== undefined;
    return isInArray;
  }

}
```

inside body.component.html

```
<!-- creating area to display movies -->
<div class="movieDisplay">
    <div id="display" *ngFor="let mov of movies">
        <img src={{mov.Poster}}/>
        <br><br><br>
        <h3>{{mov.Title}}</h3>
        <p>{{mov.Year}}</p>
        <!-- Show a clickable button if movie isnt in list, and disabled button if it is in the list -->
        <button type="submit" *ngIf="!checkNominations(mov); else nominated" (click)="nominate(mov)">Nominate</button>
        <ng-template #nominated><button type="submit" disabled="True">Nominated!</button></ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please further elaborate the problem or check this if you want let the comp know when change happen inside service , https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/a-custom-event-service-in-angular-to-subscribe-and-broadcast-messages-using-observer-pattern-95a78de8abbb

Comment: so basically, when I click the "remove" button in the footer component and it removes the item from the dataService, I want the body component to update and allow the user to select the same film again. the images I provided above show how even after the remove button is clicked, the "nominate" button stays disabled.